# The persistancy on my UIPasteboard is still active when the app is uninstalled. why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipasteboard

I use the `UIPasteboard` class to use data with severals app. The doc say that the persistancy is removed when the creator application is uninstalled. I do two app, one for copy, the other for past:

creator app:

```
-(IBAction)paste:(id)sender{
    UIPasteboard* pb = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"mytext" create:YES];
    tv_pasting.text = pb.string;

}
```

reader app:

```
-(IBAction)copy:(id)sender{

    UIPasteboard* pb = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"mytext" create:YES];
    pb.persistent = YES;
    pb.string = tf_copy.text;
}
```

I do a text copy in my first app, I paste on my second app, the text is copied, all is good. After, I uninstall my two app and reinstall the reader app. I do paste... and the older copy is still available. Why ?

Answer (score 5):

After some tests, I found that It removed the UIPasteBoard if the name of it has a link with the bundle identifier of the App.

So if my bundle identifier is

```
com.test.MyTestApp
```

the UIPasteBoard name should be

```
@"com.test.MyTestApp.MyPasteBoard"
```

Then it will be removed. This is what testing taught me.